# Explanation of behaviour in calculation of mutual inductance between two circular coils

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance, electrical-engineering

I am working on calculation the mutual inductance between to coils in a project concerning power transfer. At the moment I am working on analyzing the mutual inductance between two coils but I am running in to some answers I am do not understand fully.

For calculating the mutual inductance I use the formula where

$ M(R_i,R_j,d_{ij}) = \frac{2 \mu}{\alpha_{ij}} \sqrt{R_i R_j}
\left[ 
\left( 1- \frac{\alpha_{ij}^2}{2} \right)K(\alpha_{ij}) - E(\alpha_{ij})
\right] $ [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1hUH.png)

Where $R_i$ and $R_j$ are the radius of the coils $i$ and $j$ and $d_{ij}$ is the center-to-center distance. The functions $K(\alpha_{ij}) ,E(\alpha_{ij})$ are the complete elliptical integrals of first and second order.

I then try and simulate this in using Scipy.special, both with same and different radii:

[image: Code for calculating mutual inductance in scipy]

[image: Plotting mutual inductance using scipy]

and

[image: Plotting mutual inductance with different radii]

But the result is not what I expected at all. The mutual inductance should go as $r^{-3}$ but the plot shows the mutual inductance converging to some point not zero. I am wondering if this has something to do with the elliptical integrals in scipy but they should be a problem I think.

So my question is what is going on and how I can fix this?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1hUH.png) S. R. Khan, S. K. Pavuluri and M. P. Y. Desmulliez, "New analytical model for the characterisation of printed spiral coils for wireless power transfer," 12th European Conference on Antennas and Propagation (EuCAP 2018), London, 2018, pp. 1-5.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about coding/debugging rather than physics. A better place to ask would be Stack Overflow SE or possibly Computational Science SE.

Comment: On second thoughts, I have retracted my vote. The code is quite self-explanatory.  Your reference mentions spirals whereas in your title the coils are circular.  The formula you have used might be incorrect. It does not match the Maxwell Formula given on p 6 of [Rosa & Grover](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/bulletin/08/nbsbulletinv8n1p1_A2b.pdf) which uses the same parameter $\alpha=k$. Also on p 7 a difficulty is noted that values for $M$ are unreliable when $R_1 \approx R_2$ and $d \approx 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I might have mixed up coils and loops. My questions was related to loops. And the linked article uses a superposition of loops to describe the inductance of an Archimedean spiral, but I am just referencing it because of the equation for the mutual inductance between loops. 
I think the formulas in the two papers should be identical. Thank you for the link. The breakdown when d $\lim \inf $ might be explained there

Comment: Actually your formula does agree with that of Maxwell, except that your parameter α includes a factor of π which does not appear in formula for the corresponding parameter $k$ used by Maxwell. Try removing this and run the code again.